# Why does ( obj['arr'] || obj['arr'] = [] ).push(5); give me a "Invalid left-hand side in assignment" error?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write the fancy

> "Push on the array if the array exists; else, initialize the array and
>   then push"

implementation. I wrote in my Chrome console

```
var obj = new Object();
( obj['arr'] || obj['arr'] = [] ).push(5);
```

and I have reason to believe this should work.

According to Douglas Crockford's book *JavaScript: The Good Parts*,

> The `||` operator produces the value of its first operand if the first
>   operand is truthy. Otherwise, it produces the value of the second
>   operand.

If I type `obj['arr']` into my console, the value returned is `undefined`, which is falsy, not truthy. If I type `obj['arr'] = []` into my console, the value returned is that array `obj['arr'] = []`, which is truthy. Therefore the statement

```
( obj['arr'] || obj['arr'] = [] ).push(5);
```

should be equivalent to

```
(obj['arr'] = []).push(5)
```

which returns `obj['arr'] = [5]` as expected.

**So then why do I get a**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment(…)

**error in Chrome when I write `( obj['arr'] || obj['arr'] = [] ).push(5);` ?????**

Comment: While it is not obvious why you want that at all, is seems that `=` has higher precedence than `||`. Try parentheses around your assignment statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

order of operations... you need parens:

```
( obj['arr'] || (obj['arr'] = []) ).push(5);
```

Comment: I fail Computer Science 101 :(

Comment: @smerny - OP is defining it; I'm not worried about other cases now.

Comment: @andi, ah. I missed that